# Как дать юзеру временно доступную ссылку на запись блога wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Пользуюсь плагином Password Protected. Но бывает момент когда хочется дать доступ только для просмотра одной записи, как это возможно сделать? без регистрации юзера даже тестового.

Comment: А чем родной механизм не угодил?

Comment: родной это какой?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/jZW7t5H.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/post-password-plugin/

Как раз для решения задачи создания "секретной" ссылки на неопубликованый пост. Но он плохо плохо поддерживается.

Если кто-то знает что-то более свежее, я бы сам посмотрел. Задача показывать текст разным заказчикам перед публикацией бывает часто, а создавать всем пользователей не охота.

Comment: да, посвежее конечно было бы лучше. записи могут быть и опубликованы, только сам блог личный.

Comment: @Stax если личный тоже должно работать, но сам не проверял